# Poisson Regression in xgboost Fails for Low Frequencies

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm trying to implement a boosted Poisson regression model in xgboost, but I am finding the results are biased at low frequencies. To illustrate, here is some minimal Python code that I think replicates the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb

def get_preds(mult):
    # generate toy dataset for illustration
    # 4 observations with linearly increasing frequencies
    # the frequencies are scaled by `mult`
    dmat = xgb.DMatrix(data=np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]),
                       label=[i*mult for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]],
                       weight=[1000, 1000, 1000, 1000])

    # train a poisson booster on the toy data
    bst = xgb.train(
        params={"objective": "count:poisson"},
        dtrain=dmat,
        num_boost_round=100000,
        early_stopping_rounds=5,
        evals=[(dmat, "train")],
        verbose_eval=False)

    # return fitted frequencies after reversing scaling
    return bst.predict(dmat)/mult

# test multipliers in the range [10**(-8), 10**1]
# display fitted frequencies 
mults = [10**i for i in range(-8, 1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(np.vstack([get_preds(m) for m in mults]), 0))
df.index = mults
df.columns = ["(0, 0)", "(0, 1)", "(1, 0)", "(1, 1)"]
df

# --- result ---
#               (0, 0)   (0, 1)   (1, 0)   (1, 1)
#1.000000e-08  11598.0  11598.0  11598.0  11598.0
#1.000000e-07   1161.0   1161.0   1161.0   1161.0
#1.000000e-06    118.0    118.0    118.0    118.0
#1.000000e-05     12.0     12.0     12.0     12.0
#1.000000e-04      2.0      2.0      3.0      3.0
#1.000000e-03      1.0      2.0      3.0      4.0
#1.000000e-02      1.0      2.0      3.0      4.0
#1.000000e-01      1.0      2.0      3.0      4.0
#1.000000e+00      1.0      2.0      3.0      4.0
```

Notice that at low frequencies the predictions seem to blow up. This may have something to do with the Poisson lambda * the weight dropping below 1 (and in fact increasing the weight above 1000 does shift the "blow-up" to lower frequencies), but I would still expect the predictions to approach the mean training frequency (2.5). Also (not shown in the example above), reducing `eta` seems to increase the amount of bias in the predictions.

What would cause this to happen? Is a parameter available that would mitigate the effect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some digging, I found a solution. Documenting here in case someone else runs into the same issue. It turns out I needed to add an offset term equal to the (natural) log of the mean frequency. If that isn't immediately obvious, it's because the initial prediction starts at a frequency of 0.5, and many boosting iterations are needed just to rescale the predictions to the average frequency.

See the below code for an update to the toy example. As I suggested in the original question, the predictions now approach the mean frequency (2.5) at the lower scales.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb

def get_preds(mult):
    # generate toy dataset for illustration
    # 4 observations with linearly increasing frequencies
    # the frequencies are scaled by `mult`
    dmat = xgb.DMatrix(data=np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]),
                       label=[i*mult for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]],
                       weight=[1000, 1000, 1000, 1000])

    ## adding an offset term equal to the log of the mean frequency
    offset = np.log(np.mean([i*mult for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]]))
    dmat.set_base_margin(np.repeat(offset, 4))

    # train a poisson booster on the toy data
    bst = xgb.train(
        params={"objective": "count:poisson"},
        dtrain=dmat,
        num_boost_round=100000,
        early_stopping_rounds=5,
        evals=[(dmat, "train")],
        verbose_eval=False)

    # return fitted frequencies after reversing scaling
    return bst.predict(dmat)/mult

# test multipliers in the range [10**(-8), 10**1]
# display fitted frequencies 
mults = [10**i for i in range(-8, 1)]
## round to 1 decimal point to show the result approaches 2.5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(np.vstack([get_preds(m) for m in mults]), 1))
df.index = mults
df.columns = ["(0, 0)", "(0, 1)", "(1, 0)", "(1, 1)"]
df

# --- result ---
#              (0, 0)  (0, 1)  (1, 0)  (1, 1)
#1.000000e-08     2.5     2.5     2.5     2.5
#1.000000e-07     2.5     2.5     2.5     2.5
#1.000000e-06     2.5     2.5     2.5     2.5
#1.000000e-05     2.5     2.5     2.5     2.5
#1.000000e-04     2.4     2.5     2.5     2.6
#1.000000e-03     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0
#1.000000e-02     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0
#1.000000e-01     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0
#1.000000e+00     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for working through this and documenting it to get the conversation started.  I noticed you're using `xgb.DMatrix`; if I am not using this type of matrix, is `dmat.set_base_margin(np.repeat(offset, 4))` the same thing as adding `offset` to our dependent variable `y`?  I am also wondering if `'est__eval_metric'` should be set to `'poisson-nloglik'`.